# What is the meaning or use of { _ => } and _ = somefunctionname() in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

As in the question, why do people write code in the most confusing manner in scala as in

```
    _ = function1(arg1, arg2)
```

and

```
    anObject.method(arg1, arg2) { _ => }
```

which I fail to understand what it does.

Comment: could it be that the `_ = function1(arg1, arg2)` appears in a lengthy `for`-comprehension?

Comment: It seems as if in the second code snippet the `method` is invoked only for some side-effects, and the appended `{ _ => }` block does nothing at all. My best guess would be: this is what happens if you mix weird imperative code with functional programming in a bad way.

Comment: Intellij even gives you a warning if you have unused arguments. So to replace them with `_` is the only way to get rid of the warnings. I think if you get used to that, the code looks quite readable.

Comment: You definitely should provide more context for those lines to make any sense, especially for the second one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first question has to do with monadic style. Inside `for`-comprehensions, it is not possible to simply call a function.

```
for {
    x <- getList // <- I don't need this x!
    y = func(42)
    println(y) // <- I cannot do this!
} yield y
```

Sometimes, however, you are not interested in results and therefore don't want to give it a name.

At least Scala allows you to discard these results using an underscore:

```
for {
    _ <- getList // <- somewhat better
    y = func(42)
    _ = println(y) // <- somewhat dumb, but better than not being able to
} yield y
```

---

Scala also allows you to use underscore when you are not interested in an argument of a function, e.g.:

```
List.tabulate(3, 3)((x, _) => x) // we omitted second argument
```

produces 3x3 list with all rows having the same number

```
List(
  List(0, 0, 0),
  List(1, 1, 1),
  List(2, 2, 2)
)
```

Finally, a block with no statements is considered a block returning `Unit` (which is like `void` in java)

As a less abstract example, you can consider an iterator that does something when evaluated:

```
val it = Iterator.from(1).map(x => { println(s"x is $x"); x }).take(3)
```

Iterators are lazy, so nothing would happen until we convert it into a collection or call `foreach`. If we only care about side-effects, it's possible to write:

```
it.foreach { _ => }
```

Only after this output will be seen:

```
x is 1
x is 2
x is 3
```